# Error while fetching audio files from sdcard

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch audio files from the sdcard. Here's the code I am using:

```
//the URI where I want the query to be performed
Uri externalAudio = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

String projection[] = new String[] {"android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE"};
Cursor curExternalAudio = cr.query(externalAudio, projection, null, null, null);
//code to display result
```

The error is in the last line, but it is caused by the projection array. The error displayed in logcat is as below:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1994): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE FROM audio
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with this code ??

Comment: use `String projection[] = new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE};` instead of `String projection[] = new String[] {"android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE"};` for projection argument

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem. 
But can you explain what exactly caused the error ?

Comment: when we are passing `android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE` means we are accessing `TITLE` constant from `MediaStore`  class where `TITLE` value is `title` you can also see grepcode link i have mention in my answer for more deatil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are passing `android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE` as column name in projection Array which is not an valid column name . you will need to pass value of `android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE` which is also an String column name in ContentProvider. change your projection array as :

```
String projection[] = new String[] {android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE};
Cursor curExternalAudio = cr.query(externalAudio, projection, null, null, null);
```

**NOTE:-**

String value of [android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/provider/MediaStore.java#MediaStore.MediaColumns.0TITLE) is "title"